# grep regex to ignore comment at end of line

Tags: regex, grep, basic, non-greedy, powerbasic

I'm trying to grep through a lot of old PowerBASIC source files in search of a variable, but I'm having trouble getting `grep` to avoid matching references to the variable in the end-of-line comments.

For example:

```
ANGLE = 40    ' THIS IS A COMMENT ABOUT ANGLE'S VALUE
FOO = 3/ANGLE ' ANGLE CAN APPEAR ON RIGHT SIDE AS WELL
DELTA = 35    ' ANGLE AND DELTA AREN'T FRIENDS
```

Initially I was using:

```
# grep "\bANGLE\b.*'" SRC_FILE.BAS
```

But -- besides ignoring lines with no comments -- it also prints out lines of code which don't use `ANGLE` at all (such as the `DELTA` line). This is because those lines happen to also have a *single* apostrophe (`'`) in their comments (i.e. `AREN'T`).

I thought of piping the output to remove the lines I don't want with:

```
# grep "\bANGLE\b" SRC_FILE.BAS | grep -v "'.*\bANGLE\b"
```

But unfortunately it also removes the lines of code I do want that just happen to have "`ANGLE`" in their comments.

How do I get grep to match the lines of actual code involving `ANGLE` and ignore those lines with *only* matches in the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep "^[^']*\bANGLE\b" SRC_FILE.BAS
```

This only matches lines where everything to the left of `ANGLE` does not include `'`. It will have a problem similar to [jnylen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16719152/1806289) if there's an apostrophe in a string.

Answer (score 2):

You could take out the comments first:

```
sed "s/'.*$//" SRC_FILE.BAS | grep '\bANGLE\b'
```

This will still fail in some cases, if a string contains the word ANGLE or a single quote.  To solve this problem accurately, you would need to write a parser instead of using regular expressions.

Comment: I didn't even think of literal strings in the code. Good catch!